# how to make other events using WMPLib ?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use WMPlib.dll to play files so I found this:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
```

As you can see it only explains 2 events plyaser stats change and media error, but how can you make other events like buffering and current item name?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new player instance and attach the events like this:

```
WindowsMediaPlayer Player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
Player.Buffering += Player_Buffering;
Player.CurrentItemChange += Player_CurrentItemChange;
```

Add the handlers for the above events like this:

```
void Player_CurrentItemChange(object pdispMedia)
{
   //Do something when the current item changes.
}

void Player_Buffering(bool Start)
{
   //Do something when the player is buffering.
}
```

Protip: Use Visual Studio's autocomplete features to generate the events automatically. In the image below, if I tap the Tab key twice, I am all set to go with out manually checking the event parameters and return type.

[image]

Comment: DelegateX THANKS YOU :D , but im still dont get it what are those parameters like bool Start and (object pdispMedia)
 are other events have different paramters like those ? how can i learn all of these parameters ?

Comment: Look the image I posted in my post. When you type += after the event name, visual studio asks you to press Tab. When you press tab it enters a name for the event handler. And if you press the tab key second time, it will create the event handler (method) for you automatically. You won't need to manually see the parameters.

Comment: how to know what method in () i must type ? like if want to create.void Player_StatusChange(object pdispMedia) what do i should type in () i meant that object pdisMedia are there different methods for each handler ? how i know what i should use in ()?

Comment: Yes, there are different parameters for each method. For your convenience, you can either hover over the event name or just follow what I said in my last comment and in the last portion of my post.